# LaTeXmk, xelatex and Texmaker

Tags: xetex, latexmk, texmaker

I am trying to set up Texmaker, so I can use `latexmk` with `xelatex`, as `biber` seems already supported by `latexmk`. I confess I do not understand how I should proceed about it. 
For `latexmk`, I am actually using this command line:

```
latexmk -e "$pdflatex=q/xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode/" -pdf %.tex.
```

I have also created and modified the file `.latexmkrc` as described in the list, but this should only work from the command line.

Comment: Does settings in .latexmkrc not affect latexmk run via Texmaker?

Comment: @N.N. It seems not in my case, but I am not entirely sure. Sorry for the unhelpful answer

Answer (score 5):

I've put that line (slightly modified) in a "user command" in Texmaker

```
latexmk -e "$pdflatex=q/xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode/" -pdf %
```

and the document has been built successfully.

Comment: There also is an option `-xelatex`, but your version seems better because `-xelatex` might not include `-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode`, which seems advisable for Texmaker.

Comment: I have the same problem, and unfortunately the above solution doesn't work for me. In my case, it seems Biber cannot compile the bibliography for some reason. Latekmk complains "Missing bbl file" several times, and produces a pdf, but without the bibliography. If I manually compile with xelatex+biber+xelatex all is perfectly fine (and the bibliography appears!), so it seems it's a problem from the command given to latekmk from TexMaker, which is exactly the one given above. Maybe the program changed its command since?